# PHP convert htmentities to latin with euro sign

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters

I have a script that converts UTF8 to htmlentities. The result for the euro sign is `&#8364`. I am trying to convert this back into latin (ISO-8859-15) which I believe has the euro sign in it.

When I try

```
html_entity_decode('&#8364', ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15');
```

it does not convert it to

> €

How do I do this? (The final output will be a windows txt file.)

Edit ** I change the input string to make it more obvious as some people did not pick up on this in the second sentence.

Comment: Works for me. PHP 5.3 converts `&euro;` to 0xA4. But why don't you go with UTF-8 anyway? And Windows assumes the charset `"CP1251"` which has the Euro symbol at a different code point.

Comment: Works here too: `$ php -r "echo ord(html_entity_decode('&euro;', ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15'));"
164`

Comment: I am using numerical character symbol &#8364 for euro, not &euro; Does this work for you? I can't seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not follow the ISO charsets, it uses an older encoding:

```
html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'CP1251');
```

The Euro symbol becomes `\x88` there, whereas Latin-9/ISO-8859-15 would have `\xA4`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/ISO-8859-15/list.htm), you are correct: ISO-8859-15 does indeed support the EURO SIGN character.

When you say "it does not convert it" are you *sure* it doesn't?  Because properly encoding the character is only half of the work - you have to inform the client application (i.e., the browser) what encoding the data is encoded with, so that it may properly *decode* the bytes into characters.

You'll need a line of code that looks something like this

```
ini_set( 'default_charset', 'ISO-8859-15' );
```

Or this

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15' );
```